# VBA Import Excel date into via ADO SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, datetime-format, adodb

I am having issues trying to import an Excel field with date format of '9/27/21 1:07 PM' into SQL Server datetime field using ADODB in VBA. Below is the code I am using in my INSERT statement but it is not working. I get the error:

> System Error &H80040E14 (-2147217900)

How would I convert it in order for it to work? Thanks in advance!

```
cast(Start_Time as datetime)
```

Comment: Can you post the whole error?  With that one there's usually more that gives an indication of what is wrong.  What is the value of `Start_Time` at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your session's `dateformat` is 'mdy', eg

```
set dateformat 'mdy'
select cast('9/27/21 1:07 PM' as datetime)
```

as

```
set dateformat 'dmy'
select cast('9/27/21 1:07 PM' as datetime)
```

fails with

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 50
> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Do you mean add that 'set' code in my vba code or within the SQL code to execute?